# Can not see FXML creation option

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, tornadofx

I'm learning Kotlin language with Udemy course.
When it came to do exercise with GUI lecturer told to install TornadoFX to be able to create FMXL file. However I have already done that and as you can see on the picture still don't have that option. Could you tell me what should I do to fix it and continue my course? Thanks in advance. I'm working on Windows 11, IDE IntelliJ as you can see. [I don't have an access to create FXML file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D9XW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Click on "New" -> "TornadoFX view", just like in your screenshot, then in the window that pops up, under where you enter the name, is a drop-down menu called "Kind" where you choose either code or fxml.

[Screenshot of "Kind" drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ire1i.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Idk what kind of citations and documentations would improve upon an actual screenshot of precisely how to accomplish what the OP asks. The bot could do with improving.